# Serve images from a directory but be accessed by a different URL path

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, azure-web-app-service, url-rewrite-module

How can I specify a URL rewrite in my web.config whereby any request for an image is served from a different directory on disk?

The images are located in directory `site-root\foo\bar\images`. Normally they're accessible by `http://site-root/foo/bar/images/`

I'd like the images to be accessible via a different URL like `http://site-root/img/`

For example:

```
site-root\foo\bar\images\test.png
```

to be accessed at

```
http://site-root/img/test.png
```

I won't really need a filter for file extensions (png, gif, jpg, etc), but just rather any file/resource being requested from `img` to be read from the real directory.

How can I use ASP.NET web.config URL rewrites, or any other method, to achieve this?

I'm going for a web.config solution, as this will be deployed to Windows Azure Websites.

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved this in the past by setting up a virtual directory in IIS to map the URL to a specific folder.

Comment: Thanks David. Unfortunately, I'm using Windows Azure Websites, and thus don't have access to create virtual dirs.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this web.config rewrite rule.

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Blog Images to Thier Real Location" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^img/(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="foo/bar/images/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

From [Carlos AG's blog post IIS 7.0 and URL Rewrite](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/09/02/iis7urlrewriteseo.aspx)